# How to use WHILE in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

When retrieving 5 values using `LIMIT 0,5` and `WHILE` how to set these five values in five different ASP.NET text boxes? using the following code I am able to write as `Response.Write` but how to fix them in TextBox?

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(
    "Select nickname, city, country, zipcode from awm_profiles WHERE email LIKE '%softmail.me%' LIMIT 0 , 30",
     MyConnection);

OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == false)
{
    //throw new Exception();
}

while (dr.Read())
{
    string a = dr[0].ToString();
    string b = dr[1].ToString();
    string c = dr[2].ToString();
    string d = dr[3].ToString();
    Response.Write(a);
    Response.Write(b);
    Response.Write(c);
    Response.Write(d);
 }
```

Comment: The query in your code returns a table with 4 columns and 30 rows. In your question you talk about 5 values, so what exactly do you mean? And if you want to put each row into its own text box, how do you want to format the columns?

Comment: Using TextBoxes implies WebForms.  Don't use `Response.Write()` with webforms.  Just don't.  Put a grid (datagrid, gridview, repeater, etc) on the form, set your datareader as the grid's datasource, and call databaind on it.

Comment: @Kars, I don't understand, what example?

Comment: @svick , as onehalf suggested use a grid and give one of the column type as textbox and bound the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use some data-driven control like GridView. Check this video: [[How Do I:] Create Data-Driven Web Sites?](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-data-driven-web-sites)

In your case texboxes will have values only from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Place `TextBox` Controls in the ASPX page and then set the value using the textbox's ID:

`tb1.Text = a;`

Comment: Yes, but how to count the number of values present in the database for my input?

Comment: @Kars you want one TextBox for every value, and the nr. if values may vary?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `Response.Write(a);` put your textbox
`TextBox1.Text = a;`
`TextBox2.Text = b;` like that

Comment: @gvLeaner; Don't post your answers as community wiki, you will not get anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Data Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use like this

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(
    "Select nickname, city, country, zipcode from awm_profiles WHERE email LIKE '%softmail.me%' LIMIT 0 , 30",
     MyConnection);

OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == false)
{
    //throw new Exception();
}
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (dr.Read())
{
    string a = dr[0].ToString();
    string b = dr[1].ToString();
    string c = dr[2].ToString();
    string d = dr[3].ToString();
    builder.AppendLine(a);
    builder.AppendLine(b);
    builder.AppendLine(c);
    builder.AppendLine(d);
 }

 Response.Write(bulder.ToString());
```

Hope this will help :)